# How to manipulate Github repositories within an application in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I'm trying to create a GUI in Ruby on Rails, which handles the functions of GitHub, what tool do I use? Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried already? StackOverflow works best when you provide a more specific question after having tried some things on your own.

Comment: I'm looking for sugestions that tools i can use to create, gem's, api's..

Comment: You can check [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). Really easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently built the application to manage github/bitbucket/gitlab repositories.

For github I've used `omniauth-github` for oauth2 authorization and `octokit` to work with github api.

These are a full list of gems that I've used:

```
# github oauth2 authorization
gem 'omniauth-github'
# ruby client for github api
gem 'octokit'

# gitlab oauth2 authorization
gem 'omniauth-gitlab'
# ruby client for gitlab api
gem 'gitlab'

# bitbucket oauth2 authorization
gem 'omniauth-bitbucket', git: 'https://github.com/alexkojin/omniauth-bitbucket'
# ruby client for bitbucket api
gem 'bitbucket_rest_api'
```

Comment: I'm developing an agile project management software in Ruby on Rails that is almost done, and I want to give the programmer the option to manipulate github within the platform. I am using Omniauth-Github to authenticate so far. I would like to know if you do not have any code doing Commits, Pulls, Requests, etc. For me to understand how it works, and adapt to my project.